# How can I visualize program traces with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

To analyze multi-threaded program behaviour, I generate traces of code execution. Now, the chrome browser allows me to visualize it in a nice way:

[image]

I'd like to include a visualization like these in my TeX documents. My question is thus: is there something similar available with TikZ or pgfplots that I missed so far?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how do you do such tracing plots in Chrome/Chromium? They are awesome.

Comment: You basically generate your traces and dump them in  a specific JSON format. I wrote a bit about that [here](http://bloerg.net/2014/04/07/visualizing-trace-profile-data.html).

Comment: Since you already have some python coding experience, I think the easiest way would be to write a python script which loads your JSON file and outputs tikz commands to draw the result. If you want a more specific answer, you can provide a sample JSON file and some hints about the expected output

Comment: I thought about that too. However, this means I would need to recreate all the nice things pgfplots provides: axes, grids, ticks etc.

Comment: That beats me: I've had the very same requirement + implementational idea last week. I didn't know that chrome can do it, though. The only caveat is that my data files span a very long time range and can easily become extremely large...

Comment: Would it be possible to add to your post some raw data with some explanation of them? That `trace.json` would be a great to start experimenting with.

Comment: you can actually take a look [here](http://se.wtb.tue.nl/sewiki/wonham/gantt.py)

Comment: @Malipivo: [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/matze/97dc4e251004eb5062f5/raw/4c148813066dfb3cd97b0b55acfbf77a2d5f1594/trace.json) you go.

Comment: If you know it, could you please decode `ts` (timestamp)? In your file the last entry is `"ts": 487442.9702758789`. Even if it contains milliseconds, where is the beginning and duration or the ending of the process? If it is a time difference multiplied by 1000*1000 (according to your website), how we can get the beginning of the process? It must be stored in `tid` then (?).

Comment: The json file you provided, somehow misses some information necessary to produce the desired plot. If I understand correctly, one needs the starting time *and* the duration but I fail to see this in the json file.

Comment: @Pouya: the chrome JSON format does not specify starts and durations but starts and ends encoded by the "ph" field (which is either B or E). I know it's not very convenient but that's directly from [the spec](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CvAClvFfyA5R-PhYUmn5OOQtYMH4h6I0nSsKchNAySU/edit).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution using LuaLaTeX.

First of all, a preprocessing has to be done to your JSON data, because the field `tid` contains integers too large for lua, which are then stored as floating point numbers, with an internal rounding which makes impossible to reconstruct the original integer.

I think that those field (`tid`) should be stored indeed as a JSON string. You can change your python script which generates the JSON and store it as string. Probably the Chrome visualizer will still work. Meanwhile, I processed your data with the following python script:

```python
import json
import sys
if len(sys.argv)<3:
    print "Usage: %s input.json output.json" % sys.argv[0]
    sys.exit()
_in = open(sys.argv[1])
data = json.loads(_in.read())
_in.close()
for t in data["traceEvents"]:
    t["tid"] = str(t["tid"])
_out = open(sys.argv[2], "w")
_out.write(json.dumps(data))
_out.close()
```

Using this script and the [example JSON you provided](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/matze/97dc4e251004eb5062f5/raw/4c148813066dfb3cd97b0b55acfbf77a2d5f1594/trace.json) I produced the following JSON as input for my experiment (saved as `trace.json`):

```json
{"traceEvents": [{"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 463.9625549316406, "cat": "f", "tid": "140094068987648", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 24585.962295532227, "cat": "f", "tid": "140094060594944", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 32024.860382080078, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093981456128", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 45877.933502197266, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093973063424", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 70307.01637268066, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093964670720", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 84609.9853515625, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093956278016", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 93953.84788513184, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093947885312", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 94250.91743469238, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093964670720", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 99001.88446044922, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093964670720", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 111577.03399658203, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093939492608", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 126761.91329956055, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093947885312", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 131937.98065185547, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093947885312", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 137961.86447143555, "cat": "f", "tid": "140094068987648", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 146477.93769836426, "cat": "f", "tid": "140094068987648", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 168772.93586730957, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093931099904", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 171284.91401672363, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093947885312", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 190065.86074829102, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093947885312", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 200531.9595336914, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093377476352", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 203018.9037322998, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093939492608", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 205718.0404663086, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093956278016", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 224355.93605041504, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093956278016", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 239644.05059814453, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093931099904", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 244351.86386108398, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093973063424", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 246371.03080749512, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093973063424", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 248718.9769744873, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093931099904", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 250808.9542388916, "cat": "f", "tid": "140094060594944", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 261550.9033203125, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093964670720", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 271960.973739624, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093964670720", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 277998.9242553711, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093981456128", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 285593.98651123047, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093981456128", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 295259.952545166, "cat": "f", "tid": "140094060594944", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 296828.9852142334, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093939492608", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 309973.00148010254, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093973063424", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 310663.93852233887, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093377476352", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 314920.90225219727, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093377476352", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 328592.06199645996, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093973063424", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 330901.8611907959, "cat": "f", "tid": "140094068987648", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 342347.8603363037, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093377476352", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 353376.8653869629, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093377476352", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 374196.05255126953, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093973063424", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 376448.8697052002, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093973063424", "ph": "B"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 414726.97257995605, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093973063424", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 421860.933303833, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093964670720", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 422044.9924468994, "cat": "f", "tid": "140094060594944", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 422374.01008605957, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093947885312", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 425405.97915649414, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093956278016", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 452973.8426208496, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093377476352", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 466531.99195861816, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093939492608", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 478200.91247558594, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093981456128", "ph": "E"}, {"name": "foo", "pid": 11403, "ts": 487442.9702758789, "cat": "f", "tid": "140093931099904", "ph": "E"}]}
```

The structure of this JSON is an array of events, and for each event the following fields are stored (I give a short description of how I interpreted them and used in the diagram):

- `name`: It is the name (of the process?) to be shown in each bar of the diagram
- `tid`: It is the thread identifier, to be shown at the left of the diagram. There is one row in the diagram per `tid`. Those have to be strings, as said above
- `pid`: It is the PID (of the process to which the thread belongs, I assume). This info is not used in the diagram. It is 11403 for all the events in this example.
- `cat`: Some kind of "category", not shown in the diagram. It is `f` for all the events in this example.
- `ts`: it is a *timestamp* relative to some unknown time origin. Those timestamps have to be scaled down (divided by 100) to accomodate them to units manageable y tex/tikz. The luatex code takes care of this.
- `ph`: It contains a single letter "B" or "E", which I assume means "Begin" or "End", and thus indicates if the current event is the beginning or the ending of a thread execution. My code draws solid rectangles between one "B" and next "E" events for the same `tid`.

Indeed, in my code I do not check if the "B" and "E" events are properly sequenced. I assume that the first event of a thread is always of type "B", and after a "B" event, the next event for the same thread is always of type "E". It looks a reasonable assumption, and it holds for the example data.

Now to the code.

## Main tex file (`test.tex`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{traces}  % <-- See later
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  tid/.style = {    % Style for the column of "tid" at the left of the diagram
     anchor=south west, 
     fill=blue!10, 
     text width=3cm, 
     minimum height=6mm,
  },
  trace/.style = {  % Style for each "bar" in the diagram
     draw=blue!50!black!40, 
     fill=cyan!70!black!60,
  },
  label name/.style = {  % Style for the name appearing in each bar
     font=\small\sffamily,
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.03mm, y=6mm]  % Note the scale, it is important!
   \plotTraceFromJSON{trace.json}     % The name of the file containing the trace
   % That's all!
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## The result

After processing with `lualatex test.tex` the resulting pdf is:

[image: Result]

This result can be further embellished using tikz, since the command `\plotTraceFromJson` not only drawn the diagram, but also defined some node names which can be used as reference to add grids or annotations. See more at the end.

## The latex style file (`traces.sty`)

This is very minimalistic. It only loads the lua code, and defines a latex command to invoke it:

```
% This is file traces.sty
\directlua{dofile("luatrace.lua")}
\newcommand{\plotTraceFromJSON}[1]{
  \directlua{plotDiagram("#1")}
}
```

## The lua code (`luatrace.lua`)

Finally, the lua code reads the JSON, parses it to internal lua variables, processes it in order to group all the events pertaining to the same tid in a ordered array of pairs (begin, end) of executions, and uses the processed data to generate a series of tikz commands which draw the above graph.

This code requires another library called `JSON.lua`, which can be downloaded [here](http://regex.info/blog/lua/json). The complete file is only 29K, so I wonder if I could paste it here, just in case the provided link dies in the future...

```lua
-- This is file luatrace.lua
JSON = dofile("JSON.lua")  -- This is required, see above

local function parseJson(file)
    local f = assert(io.open(file, "r"))
    local json_txt = f:read("*all")
    f:close()
    local v= JSON:decode(json_txt)
    return (v.traceEvents)
end

local function process(data)
    local threads = {}
    for i = 1,#data do
        tid = data[i].tid
        if (threads[tid]==nil) then
            -- Create new
            threads[tid] = {name   = data[i].name,
                            pid      = data[i].pid,
                            events = {} }
        end
        table.insert(threads[tid].events, {data[i].ts,data[i].ph})
    end
    return(threads)
end

function plotDiagram(file)
    local v = parseJson(file)
    local t = process(v)

    -- Ensure ordering of the tid
    local aux = {}
    for tid,v in pairs(t) do table.insert(aux,tid) end
    table.sort(aux)

    local y = 0
    local counter = 0
    for i,tid in ipairs(aux) do
        v = t[tid]
        tex.print(string.format("\\node[tid] at (0, %f) (tid%s) {%s};",y, counter, tid))
        tex.print(string.format("\\fill[trace]  (tid%s.south east) ++(0, 0) ",counter))
        y = y-1
        counter = counter + 1
        for j = 1, #v.events-1, 2 do
            start = v.events[j][2]
            ending = v.events[j+1][3]
            tex.print(string.format(" +(%f, 0) rectangle +(%f,0.8) node[label name, midway] {%s} ", start/100, ending/100, v.name ))
        end
        tex.print(";")
    end
end
```

## Further embellishments

After the diagram is produced, some node names are available, named `tid0`, `tid1`, etc.. Those are the nodes which contain the *tid* of each thread, and thus can be used as references to draw horizontal lines in a grid.

Also, vertical lines can be drawn using the same time units than the diagram (but remembering that lua scaled all of them to 1/100).

The following code shows an example of this kind of post-processing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{traces}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  tid/.style = {
     anchor=south west, 
     fill=blue!10, 
     text width=3cm, 
     minimum height=6mm,
     font=\ttfamily
  },
  trace/.style = {
     draw=blue!50!black!40, 
     fill=cyan!70!black!60,
  },
  label name/.style = {
     font=\small\sffamily,
  },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.03mm, y=6mm]
% Plot the diagram

\plotTraceFromJSON{trace.json}

% Add background grid or other embellishments
\coordinate (right border) at (current bounding box.east);
\coordinate (left border) at (tid0.east);
\coordinate (bottom border) at (current bounding box.south);
\coordinate (top border) at (current bounding box.north);
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\foreach \y in {0,2,...,9} {
    \fill[black!10] (tid\y.south-|left border) rectangle ($(tid\y.south-|right border)+(0,0.8)$);
}
\foreach \x in {1, 2, ..., 4} {
    \draw[black!60] ($(bottom border-|left border)+(1000*\x,-0.3)$) -- ($(top border-|left border) +(1000*\x,0.3)$) node[above] {0.\x s};
    \draw[black!20] ($(bottom border-|left border)+(1000*\x+500,-0.3)$) -- ($(top border-|left border) +(1000*\x+500,0.3)$);
}
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Final]

Comment: I just wanted to say WOW.